# Keep history of DOM element

Tags: javascript, dom, undo, dom-manipulation

I need to keep a history of DOM element (i.e. div with the children). I build a diagram building app, and a user can add elements to the diagram, resize and move them. I need to have possible to undo changes.
I did it by adding JS array and add to it JSON object with the function to call when undo, will be clicked, with the parameters. For example, when a user adds a new element to the diagram I add to history JSON object: `{callback: removeElementFromDiagram, parameters: element}`.
Is there a better way to do this or any library to use?

Comment: Have a look at Function.prototype.bind or closures...

Comment: Do you have a data model of the element? In this case you could keep immutable copies of that model for every version.